# c# - Unique instance of a subclass

Tags: c#, interface, singleton, instance, subclass

I'm asking the question here cause i'm not finding the answer... Maybe i'm not looking for the right terms...

My question is pretty simple, I have an interface class in C#, the thing is that one of the requirements of the program is that one and only one instance of this "kind" of classes should be in the program...

My idea was to make it a singleton class, so for example I have an interface called ProductionCriteria and it should be 3 different subclasses, one is a given ordering criteria and the other two are different criteria too...

So, what can i do to have only one instance of any given subclass at the same time?

Another example, the user selected the Criteria (OrderByDate) so there is an instance of the CriteriaByDate class that implements ProductionCriteria, but after the production, the user changes the criteria to CriteriaByMaxAmount, so, what i need is that this subclass ocupe the same instance that the first created?

I don't know if it makes any sense, but I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a Singleton with the Factory pattern?

Comment: Mmmm, didn't think of a Factory... Would violate OC right?

Comment: @user986056 OC? Not sure what you're referring to :)

Comment: Sorry Open Closed principle? My first language is not english so i'm a little behind on these terms...

Comment: No it wouldn't violate OC, that's a very different concept.  OC means that if your classes support a plugin-style extensibility model (more or less) so that you can change it's behavior without re-writing it.  That concept has no conflict with Singletons and Factories.  You can learn more about OC here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle.
Note: OC takes a lot of practice to learn how to do correctly :).  It's okay if you start off violating it a bit, that's how you learn and grow

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will give it a look at the factory pattern to see if I can make it work via that. Thanks again!!